# Suggestions for a JavaScript form builder?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I'm looking to integrate a form builder into a site I'm using, but I'm hoping to find a library that has some or most of the functionality I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a library that will give me a nice GUI for building the form, and a JSON (or XML, or similar) output that I can play with in the `django` backend.  I'm planning to use `django` to output the finished form.

I tried running this through Google, but that only yields companies who make a business out of creating and hosting the forms online.  But nothing in the form of a library.

Any suggestions?

Comment: To the minimods: this should get wikified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you dont mind spending a bit of cash you can look at:

Machforms : http://www.appnitro.com/

The form builder itself is entirely client side JS, so you would just need to post the output (which is JSON) to django instead of their php script.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion, Matt.  I'm waiting for a reply on how this would work with licensing and the like, but I think you were dead on with what I was looking for.  These guys need some SEO.  =-]

Answer (score 17):

I have the same requirement,

I will update this answer over time but bootstrap form builder ( PHP ) seems nice

https://github.com/minikomi/Bootstrap-Form-Builder
demo : http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/

Comment: The source link to the demo is wrong. It should be   https://github.com/minikomi/Bootstrap-Form-Builder

Comment: @AkshayRawat Thanks, fixed the post, minikomi seems still very active there.

Comment: This solution is only for bootstrap 2. It seems they've never updated the project to use bootstrap 3. It's just too dated to use anymore.

Answer (score 8):

A new JS library that's just popped up might be what you are looking for: http://dobtco.github.io/formbuilder/

Project page: https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder

Answer (score 5):

Here are some:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-form-builder-plugin/

https://github.com/stas/jquery.formbuilder

you could also look at:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/visual-form-builder/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/formbuilder/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/form/

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about the Django piece since I haven't worked with that yet, but you may want to look into AlpacaJS: http://www.alpacajs.org/

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the awesome [ExtJS framework](http://www.extjs.com) to build such kind of application.
Here's an example.

[ext/formbuilder](http://tof2k.com/ext/formbuilder/)

Add a form panel, then drop a textbox and so on...dead simple.
Ext JS 2.2 and 3.0 (not yet ready) are LGPL and GPL licensed, you have also commercial subscriptions available, I think it worth to have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

[SpiffForm](https://github.com/knipknap/SpiffForm) is similar to Appnitro, but free (AGPL), perhaps it fits your needs.

Patches welcome :-). (I am the author.)

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 1):

There was a google Summer Of Code project last year that built a drag and drop form editor using the Dojo JavaScript toolkit.  It's not 100% complete in terms of the functionality I'm guessing you would want.

It does dump a javascript object representing the form which you can convert to JSON to send over the wire.

Depending on your JavaScript skill set it should give you a head start on the problem.

The demo is here:
http://jbalogh.dojotoolkit.org/dojo-svn/release/dojo/soc/test.html

Blog posts by the person working on it:
http://www.dojotoolkit.org/blog/jbalogh

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything exactly like what you want out there; probably the closest would be a rich text editor such as FCKEditor or TinyMCE.  These libraries are a bit like the UI you used to write your question in StackOverflow, except that they have toolbar buttons for the different FORM elements (or if they don't, you can easily add them yourselves).

A user faced with one of these editors (assuming you'd configured it to have buttons for FORM elements) would be able to lay out a form with basically no technical knowledge.

However, if a rich text editor doesn't work for you, then you're basically stuck with using something like the jQuery UI library (I'm thinking mainly of the Draggable sub-library) to build your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you're ready to program it yourself.  How dynamic do you want it? A simple form builder shouldn't be too hard to program using [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html), [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/) or [your-favorite-js-library](http://www.prototypejs.org/) if you want to go that route. I'd recommend GWT because it's really fun, simple to use and takes care of the incompatibilities between browsers.

Here are some thoughts for possible inputs to each form/question:

- Single line (for names etc)
- RichTextArea (similar to FCKEditor)
- Calendar date/time
- Multiple choices (checkbox)
- Single choices (list selector)

Each input needs a corresponding question, or a label. These need to be handled in your Model in Django, and represented as such in the forms view (and the editor).

I recommend you check out [how to embed a GWT application into existing templates/html](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/a3c335df1a78a097/b05dcb72aad0166d?lnk=gst&q=gwt+django#b05dcb72aad0166d) and how you can [communicate between django and GWT using json](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/ebf9e4857f0db7a2/eb393866cad61384?lnk=gst&q=hannson#eb393866cad61384)

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I you are using JSF you could use this formbuilder component:

http://code.google.com/p/jsf-form-builder/

A demo is available here:

http://www.reppe-itsolutions.at/jsf-form-builder/

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this is not the right answer, but take a look anyway, it's awesome :
you put some very **clear and simple to read** code on a Java - server and you get a full AJAX /Javascript form.
Just take a look at the demo [here](http://echo.nextapp.com/site/demo).
I swear it's really, **really** awesome.

Olivier

Comment: It does seem pretty awesome, but also not what I was looking for.