# Tool for Overlaying User Data on Government Form

Tags: css, formatting

I'm working on a project where user's submit data and then it is put onto a state form that they can print and submit.  To give you an idea of what I'm talking about, the form looks similar to an IRS 1040 form (https://www.healthykids.org/_img/document_1040.gif).

We've recently discovered that the form generated by our software isn't close enough to be accepted by some state's OCR process.

We're looking for some way to quickly create stylesheets or something similar so that the data can be overlayed on a scan of the original form and then printed.  We've tested to ensure this works, however the lost time of trying to get the positioning right for every version of the form for each state has become a huge problem.

I'm looking for a tool or technique that would help me roll out each form faster.

The web application is based on Code Igniter.  Our company prefers open source solutions but if a proven proprietary product exists we would certainly use it due to the critical nature of the issue.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the obvious. Most web IDE's do this with ease (I know both Microsoft Visual Studio and Adobe Dreamweaver would allow you to visually position the elements above the image without problems).

I take it you are looking for a tool that lets you design the forms as part of the web application itself. One of the related links points to [Suggestions for a JavaScript form builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879414/suggestions-for-a-javascript-form-builder).

Other than that, if you know your Javascript and jQuery/extjs etc, it should be pretty quick to write a simple "put the textfields above the image" (absolute-positioning + drag and drop) type of web interface.

Comment: I'm guessing the IDE option is where I'll go, however I was wondering if there was a more streamlined tool that would be faster, as I have to do hundreds of these forms and the budget is running low.