# dynamic form designer in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an asp.net mvc project which require dynamic form designer. Where there will be a list of controls there and user can select and put that control.

There will be a toolbox panel just like visual studio and then If user select textbox it will create a textbox in view of asp.net mvc.

Is there any open source or other ready made js or anything there? If there is any good example then it will be great

Thanking you in advance for anticipation and your time!!

Regards,
Jalpesh

Comment: Do you mean something like sharepoint?! Where we can design our pages in the sharepoint designer?

Comment: yes where I can design my form

Comment: What you are looking for is a javascript form designer, or a form builder: http://stackoverflow.com/q/879414/145682 My recommendation is : http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/#

Comment: form builder which can store data in xml

Comment: @deostroll : Can you please confirm that your recommendation is compatible with Bootstrap 3 ?