# JavaScript Form Layout Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

Anyone seen a good javascript / jquery based form layout manager?

I'm looking for something that has a list of form types ( select, text, textarea, etc ) and you can drag them on to a layout (form) and set the column / row span and save the info to JSON.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a similar article:  [Suggestions for a JavaScript form builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879414/suggestions-for-a-javascript-form-builder)

Found 2 nice ones out of it:

- http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/
- http://dobtco.github.io/formbuilder/